# Updating the basemap in in Plotly's density_mapbox visualization while preserving viewport

Tags: plotly-python, streamlit

Below is a simple Streamlit application that creates a Plotly density_mapbox visualization and provides a checkbox for altering the basemap used. The problem I have is that I would like to perform the basemap update without modifying the current viewport (centerpoint and zoom level). In this code, when you click the checkbox, the plot gets rerendered and the viewport is reset. I'm guessing I need to use Streamlit's caching functionality to save the current state of the Plotly visualization and use those parameters to reinstantiate the viz with the previous state. The trick is that I'm not sure how to get the current center point and zoom level. Any suggestions on how to overcome this overall challenge?

```
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=(
        [
            [32.4087249155, -100.9509696428, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.5201976084, -102.1030942593, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.434573418, -102.0592907601, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.2635930582, -101.95341361, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.4287233847, -102.0253840388, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.4872286706, -101.5455598032, "2021-01-01", 1],
            [31.5439162579, -101.4833865708, "2021-01-01", 1],
            [31.5439362581, -101.4833065695, "2021-01-01", 1],
            [31.7980713977, -102.0937650441, "2021-01-01", 1],
            [32.02050082, -103.31736372, "2021-01-01", 1],
        ]
    ),
    columns=["Latitude", "Longitude", "Date", "Count"],
)

st.set_page_config(layout="wide")
style = "carto-positron"
sat_view = st.checkbox("Dark view")
if sat_view:
    style = "carto-darkmatter"

fig = px.density_mapbox(
    df,
    lat="Latitude",
    lon="Longitude",
    z="Count",
    radius=10,
    zoom=3,
)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style=style)

# Display the figure
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

Comment: what do you mean by base map?  mapbox style?  An additional layer in mapbox layers?

Comment: @RobRaymond yes the mapbox style. see the style variable in the example code that is getting modified by the checkbox state.

Answer (score 0):

- have looked at this within scope of **plotly**. i.e. without **streamlit** layer
- logically in **plotly** this is **updatemenus**. Switching between two styles maintains whatever context each style has.  It does not move context between styles.

```
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=(
        [
            [32.4087249155, -100.9509696428, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.5201976084, -102.1030942593, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.434573418, -102.0592907601, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.2635930582, -101.95341361, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.4287233847, -102.0253840388, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.4872286706, -101.5455598032, "2021-01-01", 1],
            [31.5439162579, -101.4833865708, "2021-01-01", 1],
            [31.5439362581, -101.4833065695, "2021-01-01", 1],
            [31.7980713977, -102.0937650441, "2021-01-01", 1],
            [32.02050082, -103.31736372, "2021-01-01", 1],
        ]
    ),
    columns=["Latitude", "Longitude", "Date", "Count"],
)

st.set_page_config(layout="wide")
style = "carto-positron"
style2 = "carto-darkmatter"
# sat_view = st.checkbox("Dark view")
# if sat_view:
#     style = "carto-darkmatter"

fig = px.density_mapbox(
    df,
    lat="Latitude",
    lon="Longitude",
    z="Count",
    radius=10,
    zoom=3,
)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style=style)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {"label": s, "method": "relayout", "args": [{"mapbox": {"style": s}}]}
                for s in [style, style2]
            ]
        }
    ]
)

# Display the figure
# st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Rob for this answer. What I'm looking for is a solution where the viewport is maintained after switching styles. I see how the styles are maintained independently in the above solution. The key, I think, is to be able to look up for the current state of the viewport so that those values can be cached and imposed after the style is changed.